# Form for each user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have an ordinary form to create a Package object at `/packages/new`:

```
<%= form_for @package do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

The package model `belongs_to :partner`.

I am looking for a way to associate a new package form to a specific partner, preferably without any input from the user filling it in.

For example, if partner A sends a link to the form, I want the form to include `partner_id:A.id`.

How can I connect forms to partners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send `partner_id` param with the link which your partner will send.

Something like

```
http://website.com/packages/new?partner_id=3
```

And use the param as `hidden_field` in the form

```
<%= form_for @package do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %> 
  <%= f.text_field :address %> 
  <%= f.hidden_field :partner_id, value: params[:partner_id] %> 
  ... 
<% end %>
```

Alternatively you can also make use of [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Answer (score 0):

you can have, hidden field which passes partner_id to controller

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field

Answer (score 0):

If the partner needs to be logged in, in order to create a package, you could simply link the package to the partner in the controller right before saving it.

- As mentioned before, use params. And don't forget to allow the required params in the controller if necessary (via link, scroll down a little). [documentation: params](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters)
- Check out what e.g. .build() does for you. [more about relations and how to set them up correctly](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)